# Embedding video in PowerPoint 2010 not working

Tags: ms-office, embed, powerpoint

I'm trying to embed a video in powerpoint 2010 to autoplay when I get to that slide (ideal).

OR... if that doesn't work I'd like to hyperlink an image in my presentation to the video... and when I click on it, it autoplays (meaning, I don't have to click the play button).

I followed this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10552/how-to-add-video-from-the-web-in-powerpoint-2010/

On vimeo, I copied and pasted this provided iFrame code into my presentation:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/20241459?badge=0" width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> 

<p><a href="http://vimeo.com/20241459">Rick Astley - Never gonna give you up</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/zunebock">zunebock</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

But it threw this error... I don't see how this is possible because I copied and pasted the embed code.

```
Powerpoint cannot insert video from this embed code. Verify that the embed code is correct, and then try again.
```

Here's an image:

[image]
**So, restating my question:**

1) why wouldn't powerpoint be accepting that given embed code?

2) If it just won't work... how do I start a vimeo video automatically on page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimeo's code uses an iframe, which won't work; it sort of expects you to play the video back in a browser, not PPT.  It even mentions on the site right beneath the embed code that it's intended for iphones and such.

If you use, say, YouTube instead, PPT's help points out that you need to use the Old Embed code option, which gives you something like this:

```
<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Q7vsoVR5NX4?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Q7vsoVR5NX4?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Next problem:  The video doesn't play automatically and since it's an object (ie, a "thing" that PPT has no idea about other than to let it do whatever it's going to do), you can't force it to play (other than perhaps with code).

And finally, the site that hosts the video may restrict your ability to play it w/in PPT.  I tried a couple of YouTube vids in testing this; neither would play w/in ppt due to copyright restrictions.

Comment: @user3579215 adding major content to someone else's answer is not an appropriate use of editing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this error, a recommended solution is to embed downloaded YouTube video in PowerPoint.

This following article just aims to introduce a professional YouTube to PowerPoint Converter and a step by step guide on [how to download and convert YouTube to PowerPoint](http://mostraining.com/how-to-insert-a-youtube-video-into-powerpoint-2010/) supported format to successfully embed YouTube in PowerPoint for easy playback.